# Redraw Eclipse RCP Editor after adding a widget

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In my Eclipse plugin editor there is a button called "Add Graph" which adds a composite with a graph on another already created composite with "Grid Layout", but the created composite is not appearing until **resizing the Editor manually or switch to another editor and go back**

i have also used

```
parentComposite.pack();
parentComposite.layout();
```

but the added composite is shown up with a small size, and it`s adjusted also after **resizing the Editor manually or switch to another editor and go back**.

So my Question is how to call the same handler which runs while **resizing the Editor manually or switch to another editor and go back**. to adjust my view after adding the new composite.

---

Adding the Example:

```
public class MyEditor extends EditorPart {

private Composite compGraphesArea;

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Button btnAddGraph = new Button(container, SWT.NONE);
    btnAddGraph.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            createGraph(compGraphesArea);
        }
    });
    btnAddGraph.setText("Add Graph");

    compGraphesArea = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    compGraphesArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    compGraphesArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    createGraph(compGraphesArea);

}

private void createGraph(Composite compGraphArea) {

    JFreeChart chart = chartHandler.getChart();

    compGraphPlot = new Composite(compGraphArea, SWT.BORDER | SWT.EMBEDDED);
    compGraphPlot.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    Frame chartFrame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(compGraphPlot);

    ChartPanel label = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartFrame.add(label);
    chartFrame.pack();
    chartFrame.setVisible(true);

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setFixedAutoRange(1000000 + slider.getMaximum() / 2);

}
```

And this what i got after pressing "Add Graph":
[image]

and this what i am expecting and what i got after making any change on the Editor manually: 
[image]

Comment: `pack` causes everything to be sized to their prefered size, so if your Composite is coming out small that is the way you have set it up. Show us an [mcve]

Comment: Hello greg : Example added above

Comment: For a start I would get rid of all those `pack` calls, it is very rarely necessary to use `pack`.

Comment: Removing pack will lead that the Editor is not changing totally after pressing "Add Graph" until making any manual change on the editor (Resize or switching ) hence the added graph appears